# Automatically update agGrid table when user types in the filter box

Tags: javascript, aurelia, ag-grid

Using aurelia agGrid, I want the table to update automatically as the user types in the filter box.  Right now the user has to type in the filter box and click the check-boxes for the table to update.  I want the updating to occur without checking the checkboxes.  Here's an image:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/hylHS.jpg

I played around with the text filter parameters shown in the link below but I still can't get the auto-updating to work.  The demos they provide are properly auto-updating but I'm not sure how.  I'm interested to see if anyone can point me to the line of code that's doing this auto-updating.

https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-filter-text/

```
this.columnDefs = config.map(c => 
{
    return 
        {
            id : c.id,
            dataType : c.dataType,
            headerName : c.headerName,
            filter : true,
            filterParams : 
                {
                    textFormatter : textEntry => { 
                        return textEntry.toUpperCase(); 
                    },
                    newRowsAction : 'keep'
                },
            suppressSorting : c.dataType === 'status',
            menuTabs : ['filterMenuTab', 'generalMenuTab', 'columnsMenuTab']
        };
});
```

Comment: Is there an event you can subscribe to?

Comment: I'm currently using ag-grid in my own project.. but didn't need to use the filters. I'll update here if I find something related to your question.